react-native different height on Android and hide header on scroll
I am trying to make the header hide during scrolling equally on Android and iPhone devices. I cannot understand why, even though I’ve set the same height for my header, the height varies on different screens on Android devices. I have attached a screenshot for clarity. Perhaps I have an issue with the paddings. How can I align the header so that, regardless of the screen, it is in the same position and does not overlap with the FlatList? I checked iOS on SE and Pro versions, and it seems fine, but I might be mistaken about the paddings. Please help.

import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Platform, Text } from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  Extrapolation,
  interpolate,
  interpolateColor,
  runOnJS,
  useAnimatedScrollHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  useSafeAreaInsets,
} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const isAndroid: boolean = Platform.OS === 'android';
const statusBarHeight: number = StatusBar.currentHeight || 0;

const HEADER_HEIGHT = isAndroid ? 80 : 120;
const SCROLL_THRESHOLD = 100;
const TOP_BORDER_RADIUS = 30;
const SAFE_PADDING = 50;

const data = Array.from({ length: 15 }, (_, index) => ({
  id: index + 1,
  title: `Title ${index + 1}`,
}));

export function Header() {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      <View style={styles.details}>
        <Text style={[styles.count]}>Total:</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.count]}>10</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export function TestScreen() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const scrollY = useSharedValue(0);

  const headerHeight = HEADER_HEIGHT + insets.top + statusBarHeight;

  const scrollAnimatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const translateY = interpolate(
      scrollY.value,
      [0, headerHeight],
      [0, -headerHeight],
      Extrapolation.CLAMP,
    );
    return { transform: [{ translateY }] };
  });

  const headerViewAnimatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const backgroundColor = interpolateColor(
      scrollY.value,
      [0, headerHeight],
      ['black', 'transparent'],
    );
    return { backgroundColor };
  });

  const listAnimatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const translateY = interpolate(
      scrollY.value,
      [0, headerHeight],
      [headerHeight, insets.top + SAFE_PADDING],
      Extrapolation.CLAMP,
    );
    return { transform: [{ translateY }] };
  });

  const innerHeaderAnimatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const outputRange = [1, 0, 0];
    const opacity = interpolate(scrollY.value, [0, 120, 320], outputRange);
    return { opacity, paddingHorizontal: 16 };
  });

  const onUpdateStatusBarStyle = (scrollValue: number) => {
    if (scrollValue > SCROLL_THRESHOLD) {
      StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content');
      if (isAndroid) {
        StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#F3F2F5');
      }
    } else {
      StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content');
      if (isAndroid) {
        StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#000000');
      }
    }
  };

  const onScroll = useAnimatedScrollHandler((event) => {
    scrollY.value = event.contentOffset.y;
    runOnJS(onUpdateStatusBarStyle)(scrollY.value);
  });

  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => (
      <View style={[styles.item]}>
        <Text>{item.id}</Text>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    ),
    [],
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView edges={['bottom']}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="black" barStyle="light-content" />
      <Animated.View style={[scrollAnimatedStyles]}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            headerViewAnimatedStyles,
            {
              ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
              paddingTop: insets.top + 10,
              height: headerHeight,
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Animated.View style={[innerHeaderAnimatedStyles]}>
            <Header />
          </Animated.View>
        </Animated.View>
      </Animated.View>

      <Animated.FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#F3F2F5',
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
          borderTopLeftRadius: TOP_BORDER_RADIUS,
          borderTopRightRadius: TOP_BORDER_RADIUS,
          paddingBottom: headerHeight,
          paddingTop: 16,
        }}
        data={data}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ height: 16 }} />}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={[listAnimatedStyles, { top: -SAFE_PADDING }]}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 48,
    borderRadius: 42,
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#242424',
  },
  details: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  count: {
    paddingHorizontal: 6,
    maxWidth: 106,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
  },
  item: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    height: 76,
    padding: 16,
  },
});

